# PHP session_start doesn't work

Tags: php, session, cookies

My issue is that, when I use session_start(); in my php code, instead of a PHPSESSID cookie being set, a cookie with blank title and value "HttpOnly" is set instead. Using var_dump($_SESSION), I see that I can set session variables and they'll display on the page, but they won't display on any other page. For what it's worth, the two pages are at: login.domain.com/index.php and login.domain.com/login. The same code works fine locally, and other php files running on different subdomains on the same server work. I can't find any info, so if anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them.

This is the php on index.php:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
    ?>
```

And this is the php on login/login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$role = 0; //default to "guest"
$was_success = false; //default to a failed login
if(isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){ //if the post details are set then continue
    $pass = password_hash("PASSWORD", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    if (!isset($_COOKIE["mellifluous_loginRefer"])){
            $arr = array("Username" => $_POST["user"],
            "Error" => "No destination set!",
            "Success" => false
            );
            die(json_encode($arr));
    }

    if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $pass) && ($_POST["user"] == "USER")){
       $was_success = true;
       if ($_COOKIE['mellifluous_loginRefer'] == "home"){
          $_SESSION['mellifluous']['home']['username'] = $_POST['user'];
       }
    }
    else $was_success = false;
    $arr = array("Username" => $_POST["user"],
                 "Role" => $role,
                 "Success" => $was_success
    );
    if ($was_success) setcookie("mellifluous_loginRefer", "", time() - 10, "/");
    echo(json_encode($arr));
    //echo "You sent in: ";//Username: " . $_POST["user"] . " Password: ";//. $password;
}
else if(isset($_GET["user"]) && isset($_GET["password"])){
    die("This interface has been deprecated.");
    //$pass = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $arr = array("Username" => $_GET["user"]);
    echo(json_encode($arr));
    //echo "You sent in: ";//Username: " . $_POST["user"] . " Password: ";//. $password;
}
else{
    die("ERROR!");
}
?>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: check if you've left whitespace before the opening `<?php` right before the `session_start`

Comment: session working locally, but it does not work on another server. that is the issue isn't it?

Comment: @PrasunJajodia There is no whitespace.

Comment: @user3099298 yes, that's the issue.

Comment: i dont think the php session not work,
The simple test php session in your source code please try:
index.php
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['test']=1;
?>
login.php
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
if your login.php page show:1 that mean the php session working well
if it work well please check your current source code

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below, I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had some weird cookie settings in my apache2 conf file for that site that looked weird/out of place:

```
     Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
     Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly"
     Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; Secure"
```

Once I removed those lines, things worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check assigned values to `session.use_cookies`, `session.use_only_cookies` on php.ini file in your server.

You need to set the value of `session.use_cookies` and `session.use_only_cookies` in  php.ini:

```
session.use_cookies=1
session.use_only_cookies=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer to the two previous answer, but actually you shouldn't do that.

`session.use_only_cookies` is as security feature, it prevents from attacks using session identifiant inside URL. see php docs for more information.

```
 Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
 Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly"
 Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; Secure"
```

About this part, `HTTPOnly` is required, it prevents cookie to be stolen by an XSS attacks.In fact with Javascript, by default it's possible to show PHPSESSID value. this feature do not provide the value to the source request if is not HTTP. Not sure to be clear,
[see OWASP recommandation for more informations.](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)

Concerning `Secure` attribute,, the user agent will include the cookie in an HTTP request only if the request is transmitted through a secure channel (HTTPS).[see OWASP recommandation for this feature](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/SecureFlag)