# PHP: Session and Cookies doesn't work (session id change for each page)

Tags: php, session, cookies, https

I've a problem with Session and Cookies in a PHP project.
I looked for here, but all solutions that I found didn't work.

This is the situation: my code doesn't work only on a specific server.
On that server session id change for each page.

The server use HTTPS and, with phpinfo(), I can see that:

- Session Support  is enabled
- session.auto_start is off
- session.cookie_httponly is off
- session.cookie_secure is off

I tried this simple code:

A page set.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
setcookie("testc", "test cookie", time()+3600, '/');

$session_id = session_id();
echo "SESSION id: ".$session_id."<br>";

$_SESSION["test"] = "Test session" ;

if ( !is_writable(session_save_path()) ) {
   echo '<br>Session save path "'.session_save_path().'" is NOT writable!'; 
}
else{
    echo '<br>Session save path "'.session_save_path().'" is writable!';
}
?>
```

A page get.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$session_id = session_id();
echo "SESSION id: ".$session_id."<br>";

if( isset($_SESSION["test"]) ){
    echo "<br>Test session variable exists:<br>";
    echo $_SESSION["test"];
}
else{
    echo "<br>Test session variable not exists";
}
if( isset($_COOKIE["testc"]) ){
    echo "<br>Cookie:<br>";
    echo $_COOKIE["testc"];
}
else{
    echo "<br>Cookie not exist";
}   

if ( !is_writable(session_save_path()) ) {
   echo '<br>Session save path "'.session_save_path().'" is NOT writable!'; 
}
else{
    echo '<br>Session save path "'.session_save_path().'" is writable!';
}   
?>
```

Output for set.php:

```
SESSION id: q1340a8g2aa3op7v3od3glgkt6
Session save path "/var/lib/php5/sessions" is writable!
```

Output for get.php:

```
SESSION id: qu12anislkan3r4vr46rqlopp3
Test session variable not exists
Cookie not exist
Session save path "/var/lib/php5/sessions" is writable!
```

If I reload one page (get.php or set.php), the session id is the same only for that page.

what could be the problem?
Thanks a lot.

UPDATE:
I discovered that the session id change also in the same page. I saw the same session id because the server gives me a cached version of page. In fact if I add a GET random param to the address, the session id changes.

Comment: since your manual cookie doesn't show up either, I kind of doubt it's a php problem. check your browser for any specific hostname/ip settings that might be blocking cookies entirely for that one server

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067880/php-session-start-doesnt-work/40077841#40077841

Comment: I tried with different browsers and different PC, but the result is the same.

I have no access to php.ini, i tried with:
 ini_set ('session.use_cookies', 1);
 ini_set ('session.use_only_cookies', 0);

but the result is still the same :(

Comment: I discovered that the session id change also in the same page. I saw the same session id because the server gives me a cached version of page. In fact if I add a GET random param to the address, the session id changes.

Comment: Are you using `session_write_close()`?

Comment: I try also with session_write_close() at the end of files, but nothing change